# FQL multiquery showing empty array

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

i am usig Facebook fql.multiquery to fetch data with command line. like this

```
$queries = '{
        **"query1" : "SELECT metric, value 
                    FROM insights WHERE object_id=148945955209922 
                    AND metric="application_active_users" 
                    AND end_time=end_time_date("2011-12-10") 
                    AND period=period("month")",
        "query2" : "SELECT metric, value 
                    FROM insights WHERE object_id=148945955209922 
                    AND metric="application_active_users_city" 
                    AND end_time=end_time_date("2011-12-10") 
                    AND period=period("month")"
    }';
```

But while running this code it is showing empty Array.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first start troubleshooting your access token.  Ensure your access token has the appropriate permissions.  Secondly, ensure the queries run independently of each other by running each one separately thru the normal FQL.  You can play around with the FQL structure using the Graph API Explorer tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer